# Div resizable in angular.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to integrating jquery UI resizable in angular.js but unable to do so,
I am trying to resize the div with resize handle in angular.js but I am fail to do so.
Any help will be great.
I have already created resize directive and included jquery Ui js for resizable but its not working.

```
app.directive('resize', function() {
    return {
        // A = attribute, E = Element, C = Class and M = HTML Comment
        restrict:'E',
        //The link function is responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM.
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         element.resizable();
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the element object is a dom object. Wrap it in jquery `$` and you may get the `resizable()` method

`$(element).resizable();`

Also make sure jquery ui scripts are loaded before angularjs starts bootstrapping.

Comment: it means before angularjs have to include the jqueryui file

Comment: that's not jquery that's jqueryui, you didn't mention that.