# Resize DIV using AngualrJS and JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

All I'm trying to do is resize the DIV using AngularJS and Jquery-UI.
For this I tryied [Using jqueryUi.resizeable() with AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066731/using-jqueryui-resizeable-with-angularjs) this link but got no success.

It throws ***elem.resizable is not a function at postLink***.

Here is my directive link function:

In the process I tryind following as well:

## Load script in following order

1. Load JQuery
2. Load JQuery-UI
3. Load AngularJS

But I still got the error same error :
elem.resizable is not a function.

link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {

```
elem.resizable();
elem.on('resize', function(evt, ui) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        if (scope.callback) {
            scope.callback({
                $evt: evt,
                $ui: ui
            });
        }
    })
});
}
```

Can any one please help with this. What I am doing wrong here or it is just not possible the way I am trying ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Div resizable in angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345501/div-resizable-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 1):

I added a demo functionality

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div resizable on-resize="someFunction( $evt,$ui)">
    Hello, world !<br />
    I am resizable :)
</div>
```

-----Angular------------------------------

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);app.controller('myCtrl', function ($http, $scope) {
$scope.someFunction = function (evt,ui) {
    console.log(evt);
    console.log(ui);
};});app.directive('resizable', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        callback: '&onResize'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.resizable();
       elem.on('resize', function(evt, ui) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            if (scope.callback) {
                scope.callback({
                    $evt: evt,
                    $ui: ui
                });
            }
        })
    });
    }
};
```

});